# QGIS: How to show roads in a region?

Tags: gis, qgis, arcgis-js-api

I am working with two shapefiles in QGIS:

- roads from a country
- regions of that country

How can I only select/show the roads of one particular region?

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61753/selecting-features-within-polygon-from-another-layer-using-qgis

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select by location` or `intersect`. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61753/selecting-features-within-polygon-from-another-layer-using-qgis

Answer (score 0):

You can use "ClipMultipleLayers" plugin.

https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ClipMultipleLayers/

You have 2 options:

**Option 1:**

1. Clip regions with roads.
2. Filter regions by country name.
3. Open output file (pass 1) and Filter by country name.

**Option 2**

4. Select region feature,that you want clip,and filter.
5. Clip region with roads.

And then you only show roads and regions by country.